# HackerRank: Left Array Rotation in Python

Tags: python, programming-challenge, array, functional-programming, complexity

[Here is the problem on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-array-left-rotation). I want to know how I can improve this code. I am mainly trying to improve the following skills: Documentation, functional programming (top-down approach), accurately estimating Big O Complexity, Space Complexity, doc-testing, and readable code.

Sometimes I feel that my code is simply too clustered with documentation, so I am not sure how much or how little to add. Should I write **param** in my documentation how I have it written? Can I improve my space/time complexity for this algorithm? I tried to focus on changing the list in place so as not to increase the space complexity. Is my estimate of `O(2N)` correct for my main `array_left_rotation()` function?

If I want to write about the worst case complexity, is how I wrote it the correct way to write it and is that where I am supposed to write it?

The mysterious no return functions and other funky stuff under the `main` function are the courtesy of **HackerRank.** [Just in case you want to view it on Github](https://github.com/CleverProgrammer/Hackerrank-Problems/blob/master/Arrays:%20Left%20Rotation/array_left_rotation.py)

I wish to improve code style, space/time complexity analysis, and readability.

```
"""
Author: Rafeh Qazi
Program: Array Left Rotation (Hackerrank Challenge)
Modified: October 2016
Submit this code at: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-array-left-rotation
"""


def array_left_rotation(int_list, shift):
    """
    Given an array of n integers and a number, d, perform d left rotations on the array.
    Then print the updated array as a single line of space-separated integers.
    :param int_list: list
    :param shift: int

    Worst Case Time Complexity: O(2N)

    Worse Case Space Complexity: O(N)

    >>> array_left_rotation([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1)
    2 3 4 5 1

    >>> array_left_rotation([2, 3, 4, 5, 1], 3)
    5 1 2 3 4
    """
    pairs = new_index_value_pairs(int_list, shift)
    replace_int_list(int_list, pairs)
    print(*int_list, sep=' ')


def new_index_value_pairs(int_list, shift):
    """
    Create a list of shifted index and value tuples.
    :param int_list: list
    :param shift: int
    :return: list

    Worst Case Complexity: O(N)

    >>> new_index_value_pairs([10, 20, 30], 1)
    [(2, 10), (0, 20), (1, 30)]
    """
    return [((index - shift) % len(int_list), value) for index, value in enumerate(int_list)]


def replace_int_list(int_list, pairs):
    """
    Map the the shifted index value pairs onto the original int_list.
    :param int_list: list
    :param pairs: list

    Worst Case Complexity: O(N)

    >>> int_list = [10, 20, 30]
    >>> replace_int_list(int_list, [(0, 20), (1, 30), (2, 10)])
    >>> int_list
    [20, 30, 10]
    """
    for index, value in pairs:
        int_list[index] = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest

    doctest.testmod()
    _, shift = map(int, input().strip().split())
    int_list = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
    array_left_rotation(int_list, shift)
```

**Update**:  I am aware of the `deque` data structure from `collections` module in Python. However, I wanted to challenge myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the easiest way I can think of to do a "shift" on a list in Python:

```
def shift_list(array, s):
    """Shifts the elements of a list to the left or right.

    Args:
        array - the list to shift
        s - the amount to shift the list ('+': left-shift, '-': right-shift)

    Returns:
        shifted_array - the shifted list
    """
    # calculate actual shift amount (e.g., 11 --> 1 if length of the array is 5)
    s %= len(array)

    # uncomment this line to reverse the shift direction
    # s *= -1

    # shift array with list slicing
    shifted_array = array[s:] + array[:s]

    return shifted_array

my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# negative numbers
shift_list(my_array, -7)
>>> [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]

# no shift on numbers equal to the size of the array
shift_list(my_array, 5)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# works on positive numbers
shift_list(my_array, 3)
>>> [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

If you need this to shift backwards (to the left) with negative numbers, add the following to the beginning of the shift list function:

```
s *= -1
```

I think the above documentation is sufficient to describe everything without being too wordy.

I have added this to the [Stack Overflow Python docs.](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1494/list-slicing-selecting-parts-of-lists/24382/shifting-a-list-using-slicing#t=201610121509041633898)

Comment: I don't understand this `s %= len(array)`, your comment isn't helping clarify it for me either.

Comment: That is the modulus operator (the remainder of the division), so it is saying "what is the remainder of *split_amount / the length of the array?*" This is the amount to actually shift the "array."

Comment: Similar to `s += 2` which is the same as `s = s + 2`, `s %= 2` is the same as `s = s % 2`.

Comment: Oh no, I totally understand the use of the augmented assignment operator. That is not confusing me. I am trying to understand why we are doing it and how it helps us. Also, what does the '11 --> 1' part mean in your comment.

Comment: @CleverProgramer Oh sorry, I said that if the size of the array is 5, and the shift amount is 11, the array will be the same if shifted 11 times as if shifted 1 time (multiples of 5, or whatever the size of the array is, will leave you with the same exact array).

Comment: Another example: if the array is [1, 2, 3] (size of 3), and the shift is 7 the progression would be: [2, 3, 1] --> [3, 1, 2] --> [1, 2, 3] --> [2, 3, 1] --> [3, 1, 2] --> [1, 2, 3] --> [2, 3, 1] logically. So the result would be the same if I use the modulus first: 7 % size of the array (3) is 1 and [1, 2, 3] with a shift of 1 is [2, 3, 1] which is the same answer as before.

Comment: Ohhh! Nice. Okay, I understand better now what it means. I will review your code again tonight and let you know if I make progress in my understanding. Thank you so much for the back and forth.